# How to find local IP adresses

Tags: java, android, networking

I want to make an app which detects all ip4 addresses in the network. I searched a bit on the internet and found a YouTube tutorial for a JAVA desktop application. Becouse android apps can  be programmed in JAVA i used that same code for the app.
code:

```
try {
    Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
        Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();

        while(ee.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
            System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

for a desktop JAVA application this code will be fine. However when i try and run this code with the android sdk also based on JAVA i get null.
Can any one explain this to me?
code in the android part:

```
try{
   Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
   while(e.hasMoreElements()){
       NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
       Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
       int ii = 0;
       while(ee.hasMoreElements()){
           InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
           ips[ii] = i.getHostAddress();
           ii++;
        }
   }
```

}
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

```
 }
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate networking permissions listed in your manifest?

Comment: _Where_ do you get null.

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Comment: In the android part i placed it in a string array instead of the system.out.println. then i printed the text from the array in a textbox which only shows null.

Comment: can you use jquery in your android app?

Comment: I started with android apps today so i don't really know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// AndroidManifest.xml permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```